# Reg exp to replace ampersands but not html entities

Tags: php, regex

In the code below I want to replace plain ampersands with "and" while ignoring the ampersands that are being used as part of an html entities (ex: ")

I've tested my expression &(?!([\w\n]{2,7}|#[\d]{1,4});) over at http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr/ and it matches what I want.

However, when I run this code, the results are blank.

```
$content = "&quot; Apples & Oranges &quot;";
$content = preg_replace("/&(?!([\w\n]{2,7}|#[\d]{1,4});)/g","and",$content); 

echo $content;
```

Is my approach flawed somehow or do I just have a syntax issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `g` flag and it should work fine.

Note that it seem to me that you'd expect and ampersand to be surrounded spaces, so the following could be a simplified solution:

```
$content = preg_replace("/\s/&\s/"," and ",$content);
```

Although I realise that this might allow mistyped text to cause encoding errors. If there is a space missing.

Comment: doesn't really do the right thing unless the right thing was intended to be a bad idea.

Comment: Removing the g allowed the code to do what I intended it to do (regardless of whether it's a bad idea or not)

Comment: does it work with, say, the string `"1 & 2 & 3"`? I'd think that'd fall in the scope of what you wanted.

Answer (score 3):

PHP donť know g-modificator, just remove g after regexp declaration. This works:

```
$content = "&quot; Apples & Oranges &quot;";
$content = preg_replace("/&(?!([\w\n]{2,7}|#[\d]{1,4});)/","and",$content); 

echo $content;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this consistently.  How would you know if someone including &amp; wants it to literally print "&amp;" or an ampersand?  Don't attempt mixed escaping... down that path lies cross-site scripting attacks.

(And oddly, stackoverflow also does semi-encoding, and it broke my posting.  Cretins.)

Comment: It's in a backend / controlled environment so I know what content to expect and a literal print of &amp would not ever be necessary.